# mod_shared_roster_ldap configuration not working. How to make it work?

Tags: mongoose-im

I am setting up OpenLDAP along with Mongooseim. I don't have a detailed knowledge about ldap. I was able to set up authentication with LDAP, but I am not able to set up `mod_shared_roster_ldap`. I want all the users in each others roster.

My example config is this:

```
{ldap_servers, ["test.example.com"]}.
{ldap_port, 389}.
{ldap_rootdn, "cn=admin,dc=test,dc=example,dc=com"}.
{ldap_password, "example"}.
{ldap_base, "ou=users,dc=test,dc=example,dc=com"}.
{ldap_uids, [{"uid", "%u"}]}.

{mod_shared_roster_ldap, [{ldap_base,"ou=users,dc=test,dc=example,dc=com"},
  {ldap_groupattr,"cn"},
  {ldap_gfilter,"(&(objectclass=groupOfURLs)(cn=%g))"},
  {ldap_groupdesc, "description"},
  {ldap_memberattr, "member"},
  {ldap_memberattr_format,"cn=%u,ou=Users,dc=xmpp,dc=graphed,dc=io"},
  {ldap_ufilter,"(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(cn=%u))"},
  {ldap_userdesc, "cn"},
  {ldap_auth_check, "off"},
  {ldap_user_cache_validity, "10"},
  {ldap_group_cache_validity, "10"}
]}
```

I took some help from https://www.ejabberd.im/mod_shared_roster_ldap